# My WebAPI responses 301

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a Chat Bot for the Streaming Service Twitch.tv. They can provide webhooks which request your api. Everytime when I want to register a webhook and Twitch tries to contact my api, my api responsed with 301 for no reason. I don't response to 301 in my code.

I don't use https and a few weeks ago it worked.

I would be happy if someone could help me.

Comment: where are you hosting your api?

Comment: windows server by strato

Comment: I would check the config on Strato. They will handle the request first. If strato is forcing HTTPS, I could see them returning a 301 before your API got a chance to process the request. What is the new location for the 301? Do you have logs to see the response is coming from your API or middleware?

Answer (score 0):

u can try to add this Propertie in your `HttpWebRequest`

```
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true
```

that if u use `HttpWebRequest`. so pls share your request code